# Phrase that is more business-appropriate than "got screwed"?

Tags: phrase-requests, phrases, phrasal-verbs

What is a more business-appropriate phrase that has the same meaning as *"got screwed"* (the non-sexual meaning).

In all the examples below, the people *"getting screwed"* were promised (or had reasonable expectations for) a product or service, but that product/service did not live up to the promises/expectations.

- "His Tesla had problems yet again.  He shouldn't have bought that thing.  He *got screwed*."
- "Amazon sent them another rancid food product.  They *got screwed*."
- "Costco claims they have a good return policy, but they wouldn't let her return that defective product.  She *got screwed*."

In the comments, community member StuartF recommended *"was disappointed"*.  This is a step in the right direction because it captures the *feeling* and *experience* of someone *getting screwed* (again, in a non-sexual way).  Answers capturing this essence (*or would that be "these essences"?*) are preferred.

Comment: *Cheated* or *ripped off* would work in the examples.

Comment: Or *was disappointed* if you want to be milder; the product *failed to live up to their expectations*.

Comment: Fyi, to get screwed comes from the sexual meaning and really can't be divorced from it. Just saying... She was taken for a ride. if you like colloquialism. What level of language (register) are you looking for?

Comment: @Lambie Thanks. That's what I thought could be the case (or could at least be perceived) and want to avoid anything sexual.  I think "taken for a ride" has the same issue.  What do you mean by *"level of language (register)"*?  If you are referring to formality, I am open to answers with all levels of formality.  I just want to avoid anything inappropriate like cussing or sexual references.

Comment: @StuartF I really like your suggestion of *was disappointed* because it captures the *experience* the of the people "getting screwed".  I'll edit the question to add that important detail.

Comment: An old fashioned term is *Taken down the garden path* meaning taken advantage of with one or more excuses, lies and deceptions. Not sure if it would fit in your modern idiom.

Comment: @Elliot Wow... that's a wonderful expression.  I do think it's a bit antiquated, but I appreciate it nonetheless.  Maybe if we all start using it, we can spark a revival?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/screwed

Answer (score 1):

In business language, you could say that the injured party was deceived, defrauded, or swindled.

However, in the best business language (using your examples), you should use the active voice:

- "His Tesla had problems yet again. He shouldn't have bought that thing. Tesla's quality claims are deceptive."
- "Amazon sent them another rancid food product. Amazon's quality control is a swindle."
- "Costco claims they have a good return policy, but they wouldn't let her return that defective product. Costco defrauded her."

Comment: Fan of active voice here, but *got screwed* so clearly has the emphasis on the victim, it may be a shame to fix the voice to active.

Comment: Welcome Melissa! Deceived, defrauded, swindled... oh so close!  Of the 3, I think *deceived* is the best match, but I think something that more aligns with the *feeling* and *experience* of getting screwed would be even better.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yosef - I fully understand and appreciate your perspective. Focusing on the actual victimization has its merits. Perhaps "was defrauded" is then a better take. 

Thanks for the welcome, EASH. What do you think about duped as a possibility?